# When will java change to 64bit addressing and how can we get there faster?

Tags: java, 64-bit

Having to work with large files now, I would like to know when the java libraries will start switching to long for indexing in their methods.

From Inputstreams read(byte[] b, int off, int len) - funnily there is long skip(long) also - to MappedByteBuffer to the basic indexing of arrays and lists, everything is adressed as int.

Is there an official plan for enhancment of the libraries?

Do initiatives exist to pressure oracle into enhancing the libraries, if there is no official plan yet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

p42 of slides at Simon Ritter's PDF [To Java SE 8, and Beyond! - QCon London](http://qconlondon.com/dl/qcon-london-2012/slides/SimonRitter_TheFutureOfTheJavaPlatformJavaSE8Beyond.pdf) indicates that it is scheduled for Java 9.

Incidentally, the keyword you were lacking to find this yourself with Google in 10 seconds is [JSR](http://www.google.com/search?q=jsr+64-bit+arrays).

Comment: I had to vent some frustration, and the visions of Java9 will be to late for me.

Answer (score 4):

files can already be addressed by `long`s and having a byte buffer of over **2 GigaByte** is a waste and will lead to a OutOfMemoryException very fast on 32 bit machines (use multiple byte buffers if you need to have that big of a range)

also the FileChannel.map takes longs to specifiy the offset and size allowing you to map passed the 2GB mark

also RandomAccessFile uses a long for the seek index

Comment: Why would it be wasteful to have a byte buffer over 2Gb?  I have the same need myself.  I have 16Gb on my development laptop and 128Gb on my largest server. The "multiple ByteBuffer" workaround is inefficient.